# Remove duplicate value from array within multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

At the moment I have this array:

```
    array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
       ["cluster"]=>
       string(3) "ICT"
       ["opleiding"]=>
       string(32) "Applicatie- en mediaontwikkeling"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
       ["cluster"]=>
       string(3) "ICT"
       ["opleiding"]=>
       string(21) "ICT cluster opleiding"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
       ["cluster"]=>
       string(15) "nog een cluster"
       ["opleiding"]=>
       string(25) "nog een cluster opleiding"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
       ["cluster"]=>
       string(8) "Techniek"
       ["opleiding"]=>
       string(26) "Techniek cluster opleiding"
   }
}
```

From this array I would like to be able to remove duplicate clusters, in this case "ICT"(Could become more eventually).

This array comes from the following query:

```
        $result_array = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT cluster.cluster, 
        opleiding.opleiding 
        FROM opleiding 
        INNER JOIN cluster 
        ON opleiding.cluster_id = cluster.cluster_id 
        GROUP BY opleiding.opleiding", ARRAY_A);
```

So, what my desired array would look like:

```
    array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
       ["cluster"]=>
       string(3) "ICT"
       ["opleiding"]=>
       string(32) "Applicatie- en mediaontwikkeling"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
       ["opleiding"]=>
       string(21) "ICT cluster opleiding"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
       ["cluster"]=>
       string(15) "nog een cluster"
       ["opleiding"]=>
       string(25) "nog een cluster opleiding"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
       ["cluster"]=>
       string(8) "Techniek"
       ["opleiding"]=>
       string(26) "Techniek cluster opleiding"
   }
}
```

How would I approach this issue? Should I change something within my query? Or is my initial thought to remove the value from the array correct, and then how would I do this?

My output function:

```
public function getOpleidingCluster()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $return_array = array();
    $result_array = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT cluster.cluster, opleiding.opleiding 
    FROM opleiding 
    INNER JOIN cluster 
    ON opleiding.cluster_id = cluster.cluster_id 
    GROUP BY opleiding.opleiding", ARRAY_A);



    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($result_array);
    echo "   </pre>";
    // For all database results:
    foreach ($result_array as $idx => $array) {
        // New opleiding object
        $koppelOpleidingCluster = new ClusterOpleiding();
        // Set all info
        $koppelOpleidingCluster->setCluster($array['cluster']);
        $koppelOpleidingCluster->setClusterId($array['cluster_id']);
        $koppelOpleidingCluster->setOpleidingId($array['opleiding_id']);
        $koppelOpleidingCluster->setOpleiding($array['opleiding']);
        // Add new object to return array.
        $return_array[] = $koppelOpleidingCluster;
    }
    return $return_array;
}
```

Getting the data on the page:

```
        <table border="1">
        <?php
        $koppelOpleidingCluster = $clusterOpleiding->getOpleidingCluster();
        foreach ($koppelOpleidingCluster as $koppelOpleidingCluster2){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;"> <input type="hidden" name="clusterId" value=" <?php echo $koppelOpleidingCluster2->getClusterId(); ?>"></td>
                <td name="cluster"> <?php echo $koppelOpleidingCluster2->getCluster(); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;"> <input type="hidden" name="opleidingId" value=" <?php echo $koppelOpleidingCluster2->getOpleidingId(); ?>"></td>
                <td name="opleiding"> <?php echo $koppelOpleidingCluster2->getOpleiding(); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php

        }
        ?>
        </table>
```

opleiding means education

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something? Or enters here and "do it instead of me"?

Comment: Could you explain *Why*  you want to delete that key? It looks like you are thinking of some particular output -- but suppressing repeated values is something you would do in the output process itself, not in the data structure.

Comment: I've tried alot of possible solutions that I've found here on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to get it to work and I'm kinda at a loss now.

Comment: I would suggest another data structure. But without knowing what you need it for it is hard to tell. Your desired output structure just would not be something I would ever go for. Please explain.

Comment: @trincot Well I want to remove it because it's not supposed to be there to begin with. The idea is that you have clusters and that clusters have educations. Right now it outputs like this:
ICT
   <education belonging to ICT>
ICT
   <education belonging to ICT>
The desired output should be, though:
ICT
   <education belonging to ICT>
   <education belonging to ICT>

I don't want it to repeat ICT multiple times.

Comment: If you are concerned with output, then you should not change your array, but the function that is responsible for outputting it. Please provide the code which outputs the array, and we can discuss that code/function.

Comment: @trincot Thanks alot so far for your interest! I edited my post with more details. Is it good like this?

Comment: Yes, that makes the question complete;  I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired array structure you want to get to is not really something I would advise to go for. It is best practice that all elements in the array have the same keys.

You seem to look for a way to suppress repeated values in your *output*. It is a mistake to try to make your array match your desired output. Instead leave the array as it is, and *only* make your code that iterates it aware of repeating values, so that it will not output them.

Before getting to that, there is another point to make about your SQL query. It violates a rule that if you have a `group by` clause, the `select` clause should only have either aggregated expressions or expressions that occur in the `group by` clause.  In this particular case it seems to me that you can skip the `group by` clause. Instead add an `order by cluster.cluster, opleiding.opleiding` clause so that it is guaranteed that duplicate clusters will appear without interruption. Or to say it differently: it guarantees that all educations belonging to the same cluster are listed together.

Now to the altered output code. Use an extra variable that will be used to detect repeating values, and add an `if` block that will only display the cluster row when it is not a repetition:

```
<?php
    $prevCluster = ""; // <----- add this
    $koppelOpleidingCluster = $clusterOpleiding->getOpleidingCluster();
    foreach ($koppelOpleidingCluster as $koppelOpleidingCluster2){
        if ($koppelOpleidingCluster2->getClusterId() != $prevCluster) { // <----
?>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none;"> <input type="hidden" name="clusterId" value=" <?php echo $koppelOpleidingCluster2->getClusterId(); ?>"></td>
            <td name="cluster"> <?php echo $koppelOpleidingCluster2->getCluster(); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
        } // <-----
        $prevCluster = $koppelOpleidingCluster2->getClusterId(); // <-----
?>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none;"> <input type="hidden" name="opleidingId" value=" <?php echo $koppelOpleidingCluster2->getOpleidingId(); ?>"></td>
            <td name="opleiding"> <?php echo $koppelOpleidingCluster2->getOpleiding(); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! In my case I only had to make it getCluster instead of getClusterId, but other than that this works!
Also, thanks alot for the other feedback next to actually solving my problem, like making my query better and explaining why certain things are bad! I appreciate it alot :)

Comment: Graag gedaan! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR) use this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Before posting an answer it would be good to first *test* it on the input that the Asker has provided and see whether it produces their desired output.